# Loaded html requests static content from parent directory

Tags: scala, spray, akka-http

How can I solve issue of missing static content when serving html from Spray (or Akka-Http) ? Base url of my service is `/api` (even though it should be irrelevant in this case).

Here is my route

```
get {
  pathPrefix("swagger") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      getFromResource("swagger-ui/index.html")
    } ~
      getFromResourceDirectory("swagger-ui")
  }
}
```

Loaded html can find css and js file when I open it as

`/api/swagger/`

but when I open

`/api/swagger` (without trailing slash)

loaded html attempts to get content from

`/api/css/reset.css` instead of `/api/swagger/css/reset.css`

How should I rewrite my route to cover both cases ?

Comment: Hi.. have you gotten swagger to work with akka-http yet ?  there is an example for spray+swagger in typesafe activator... but akka-http is newer, so i'm hoping to find an example for that.  thanks in advance -/chris

Comment: answering my own question... seems like swagger integration is not on akka-http teams priority list @ the moment.  i will probably stick w/ spray for time being. > https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/16591    -cb

Comment: @ChrisBedford It's unlikely Akka team will ever spend time on it. I heavily use both and I gotta tell you that Swagger team is fantastically unresponsive, don't fix bugs I reported for months and etc. They have poor support for generics, you can't automagically support Akka/Spray DSL and etc. One of their leads even closes my bug reports with remarks such as "it works for me". Wtf. So be aware of all this. It's overal really bad project to depend on.

Comment: wow. sorry you had that trouble. would you recommend another framework ?

Comment: @ChrisBedford Not really, the rest is even worse :) I ended up forking Swagger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding redirect. If anyone knows more elegant solution please post.

```
pathPrefix("swagger") {
  CachingDirectives.cachingProhibited {
    pathEnd {
      redirect("/api/swagger/", StatusCodes.TemporaryRedirect)
    } ~
      pathSingleSlash {
        getFromResource("swagger-ui/index.html")
      } ~
      getFromResourceDirectory("swagger-ui")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `redirectToTrailingSlashIfMissing` directive instead.

ref: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/redirectToTrailingSlashIfMissing.html